# TFS2015 - Display all shared and user owned notifications and their owners

Tags: mysql, tfs, notifications, tfs-2015

I am trying to write a SQL query which would list all shared and user owned VSTS on change notifications on TFS 2015 On-Premise. From what I've researched, the notifications should be stored in tbl_EventSubscription table, but there's no info there about whether the event is user owned or shared, just a SubscriptionID of who's subscribing and I don't know where to search for the owner.

If there's a possibility to solve this problem with REST API, it will help as well.

Any help or guidance will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I think I got it:

```
   SELECT Notif.Id AS 'Notification Id',
          Notif.EventType AS 'Event Type',
          Notif.Classification AS 'Notification Classification',
          Const.IdentityDisplayName AS 'Notification Owner'
     FROM [Tfs_Development].[dbo].[tbl_EventSubscription] Notif
LEFT JOIN [Tfs_Development].[dbo].[Constants] Const ON Const.TeamFoundationId = Notif.SubscriberId
 ORDER BY Notif.Id
```

@PatrickLu-MSFT I don't know why, but I don't have tbl_security_identity_cache in Tfs_Configuration, but I have it in Tfs_Development and it's empty. I went with Tfs_Configuration.dbo.tbl_Identity as the reference for user names but it didn't return me names for team subscribers and even some of the users, so in the end I'll go with my solution.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It's not suggest you dig into the TFS database directly. Do not make any changes to the TFS DBs, otherwise you may lose the support from Microsoft.

Since you already got the SubscriptionID, To find out which user identity is hidden behind the GUID in the "SubscriberId" column, you can use the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT  es.Id, 
        es.EventType, 
        es.Expression, 
        sic.mail_address, 
        sic.computed_display_name 
FROM    tbl_EventSubscription es 
JOIN    [Tfs_Configuration].[dbo].tbl_security_identity_cache sic 
ON      sic.tf_id = es.SubscriberId 
WHERE   es.Id = 123
```

More details please take a look at this blog: [Who created that TFS event subscription?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/vstsblog/2011/03/23/who-created-that-tfs-event-subscription/)